# What is the equivalent for EF6 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityKey in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, .net-5

I have the following code in .net framework using EF 6.

```
PropertyInfo[] propInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperties(); //myObject is of type T
foreach (PropertyInfo col in propInfo) {
    if (col.PropertyType != typeof(System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityKey))
           //do something
}
```

Now that I'm migrating to .Net 5 and EF Core, how do I get the equivalent for `typeof(EntityKey)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the following API:

```cs
var et = ctx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
var properties = et.GetProperties();

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (!property.IsKey())
    {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I don't have access to the dbcontext in this class.. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: If don’t have access to IModel, I do not think it is possible

Comment: I can use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel, But without the instance of DbContext, is it of any use? @Svyatoslav-danyliv

Comment: Actually you need just `IModel` instance from `DbContext`. It is metadatata for mapping.